# R: How to compute AUC and ROC curve for ´bgeva´ objekt/model?

Tags: r, roc, auc

Since I have data with binary response, but rare events, I would like to improve its forecast by fitting a `bgeva` model instead of a `gam` model. To prove and compare it´s prediction accuracy and compare it to other models that I tried, I need to calculate AUC and plot a ROC curve.

The problem is that my code, which works with `glm` and `gam`, does not work with `bgeva` object. Precisely, the use of the function `predict()` prints the Error:
`no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "bgeva"`
and my friend Google did not find any solution for me.

Here is one simple Example from `bgeva()` package and the code that I used to calculate the AUC and plot the ROC curve for `glm` and `gam` objects:

```
library(bgeva)

set.seed(0)
n <- 1500
x1 <- round(runif(n))
x2 <- runif(n)
x3 <- runif(n)
f1 <- function(x) (cos(pi*2*x)) + sin(pi*x)
f2 <- function(x) (x+exp(-30*(x-0.5)^2))
y <- as.integer(rlogis(n, location = -6 + 2*x1 + f1(x2) + f2(x3), scale  = 1) > 0)
dataSim <- data.frame(y,x1,x2,x3)

################
# bgeva model: #
################
out <- bgeva(y ~ x1 + s(x2) + s(x3))

# AUC for bgeva (does not work)##################################
library(ROCR)
pred <-as.numeric(predict(out, type="response", newdata=dataSim))
rp <- prediction(pred, dataSim$y) 
auc <- performance( rp, "auc")@y.values[[1]]
auc

################
# gam model:   #
################
library(mgcv)

out_gam <- gam(y ~ x1 + s(x2) + s(x3), family=binomial(link=logit))

# AUC and ROC for gam (the same code, works with gam) ############
 pred_gam <-as.numeric(predict(out_gam, type="response"))
 rp_gam <- prediction(pred_gam, dataSim$y)

 auc_gam <- performance( rp_gam, "auc")@y.values[[1]]
 auc_gam

 roc_gam <- performance( rp_gam, "tpr", "fpr")
 plot(roc_gam)
```

Comment: With `str(out)` I realised, that there are no fitted values for the model in the `bgeva` object. Maybe someone knows how to calculate them manually? Then I don´t need the `predict()` function to work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

#You can to calculate

```
pred <-as.numeric(predict(out$gam.fit, type="response", newdata=dataSim))
```

#your example

```
> auc
[1] 0.7840645
```